# why does the author write 'This makes sense and is a logical argument ~'?

Tags: meaning, usage

I have a couple of questions.

Firstly, why does the author write ***This makes sense and is a logical argument ~*** ? Does it mean that in the perspective of eastern folks, it is sensible to think that way because of the lack of information about western teams?

Next, ***what can they do*** is not finished with a question mark. Is it a kind of typo? Or, is it sometimes permitted without a question mark?

> If it is during the regular season in any sport like baseball,
> basketball, or hockey, and the game starts at 7:00 p.m. or 7:30 p.m.
> on the West Coast (10:00 p.m. or 10:30 p.m. start time in the east),
> how many fans are going to stay up until after 1:00 a.m. on the East
> Coast? Not many. So the result is an East Coast bias that definitely
> exists, because they miss many of the games that happen on the West
> Coast and don’t get to know these teams as well. Sure, they get all
> the information the next morning, but not seeing the games live as
> they do on the East Coast can hinder their view of the western teams.
> This is why those in the east think that, more often than not, the
> East Coast has better teams than the West Coast. ***This makes sense
> and is a logical argument***, but is it fair? Not always, but ***what
> can they do*** besides recording every game and watching it in the
> days or weeks to come (which I’m sure rarely happens). The East Coast
> bias will always exist, through no one’s fault. Time is of the essence
> and you play the cards you’re dealt by choosing where you live.

[Sports Fan 101: Score the Balance in Your Relationship](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=tmwBBD8e5XEC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=The%20East%20Coast%20bias%20will%20always%20exist,%20through%20no%20one%E2%80%99s%20fault.%20Time%20is%20of%20the%20essence%20and%20you%20play%20the%20cards%20you%E2%80%99re%20dealt%20by%20choosing%20where%20you%20live.&source=bl&ots=8CcTVYhVqP&sig=ACfU3U0_L95H0auOOpcOhWerVwmrQGTJtw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxsZXo7LbvAhUCK6YKHccbBp8Q6AEwAHoECAMQAw#v=onepage&q=The%20East%20Coast%20bias%20will%20always%20exist%2C%20through%20no%20one%E2%80%99s%20fault.%20Time%20is%20of%20the%20essence%20and%20you%20play%20the%20cards%20you%E2%80%99re%20dealt%20by%20choosing%20where%20you%20live.&f=false)

Comment: The entire argument is based on Time Zones and when you can see games. It is well explained in the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense... means that people conclude that their teams are better simply because it’s harder to get information on other teams. They are reasoning from what they know. It’s logical, but as the author says, not always correct.

What can they do... is part of the sentence, not its own sentence. You can tell this by looking at the next word, *besides*, which tells you the undesirable option that remains for them to do.

Answer (score -4):

Q. **why does the author write 'This makes sense and is a logical argument**

I have no knowledge of baseball, basketball, or hockey as these are mainly American sports. However I think you will find this paper makes little sense and I would argue that **This makes sense and is a logical argument** is not correct.

I would therefore have to conclude that the  reason that reason the the **author has written this is because he is biased to support his own argument**.

---

My reason for this answer.

It is well established through out the world than fans mainly support their local, regional and national teams. It also normal that a fan will not switch his allegiance to another local team even if his/her team is not so successful even if the "run of bad luck" lasts for several years. The reasons for this are complex and extend beyond obvious reasons like you are physically able to support your local team "after work" as you do not need to travel far.

Comment: People choose which teams to follow. If it’s harder to get info on a team, it’s harder to follow them, and they become less of an option. Whether or not this happens the author even acknowledges in the paper! However it’s still a logical argument.

Comment: @ FeliniusRex Yes I will accept that. Also since I wrote the answer I have been reading up a little on American fans and they seem to be "in general" very different from UK ones. However I still feel that for someone to up vote their own argument is bad form :)

Comment: @ FeliniusRex P.S. Taking comfort from your comment. It also makes me happy to think that many American citizens would prefer to support a National football team that is not American.